# convert jQuery hover to click

Tags: jquery, imagemap

I have this piece of jQuery that changes the image when the user hovers over a certain area (using imagemap).

I want to change it to a click function, but just changing "hover" to "click" isn't working.

I also suspect that the click version can be vastly simplified.

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    //set off state 
    var nav_off = "images/PWRwheel/000.png";
    // functions for over and off
    function over(image) {
        $("#main-nav").attr("src", image);
    }
    function off() {
        $("#main-nav").attr("src", nav_off);
    }
    $("#imagemap area").hover(
        function () {
            var button = $(this).attr("id");
            over("images/PWRwheel/00" + button + ".png");
        },
        function () {
            off();
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<map id="imagemap" name="imagemap">
    <area id="8" shape="circle" coords="203,106,52" href="#" />
    <area id="7" shape="circle" coords="99,207,52" href="#" />
    <area id="6" shape="circle" coords="100,349,52" href="#" />
    <area id="5" shape="circle" coords="200,459,52" href="#" />
    <area id="4" shape="circle" coords="353,459,52" href="#" />
    <area id="3" shape="circle" coords="454,350,52" href="#" />
    <area id="2" shape="circle" coords="456,209,52" href="#" />
    <area id="1" shape="circle" coords="352,103,52" href="#" />
</map>
```

To see how it currently functions, go here http://safespacetn.org/tools.html
scroll to bottom and click one of the Domestic Violence Evaluation Wheels.

Answer (score 1):

when you want to use the `click` eventhandler you have to kick the second function from your listener. Code will look like this then.

```
  $("#imagemap area").on('click', function() {
    console.log("hello")
    var button = $(this).attr("id");
    over("images/PWRwheel/00" + button + ".png");
  });
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e7qxhgfy/2/

Answer (score 0):

To make this work with a `click` handler you need to change the logic so that the new `src` is provided to the element based on its current value.

Also note that as your `over()` and `off()` functions are each wrappers for a single line of code they are almost entirely redundant and can be removed. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  let $nav = $('#main-nav');
  let defaultSrc = 'images/PWRwheel/000.png';

  $("#imagemap area").on('click', function() {
    let src = $nav.attr('src') == defaultSrc ? "images/PWRwheel/00" + this.id + ".png" : defaultSrc;
    $("#main-nav").attr("src", src);
  });
});
```

Comment: This works generally.  Thank you.  However, it doesn't work as I had hoped.  When you click in one area, it indeed changes the image.  But when you click in another area, instead of changing to that image, it changes back to the default/original image.  Then if you click again, it changes to the correct image.

Comment: In which case I would assume the `src` doesn't match the default in all cases in your HTML

Comment: I don't think so.  For example, if you click only one image area, it changes back and forth between the default image and the image that should be triggered for that area.  Instead, clicking the same area should just keep triggering the image assigned to that area.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate that behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/jfazkuxb/1/

Comment: http://safespacetn.org/wheel01.html#

Click on any subject....then click again.  Instead of staying on that subject, it toggles between the deafult image and the correct image.